# How to hide file system structure of SaveFileDialog in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog, filedialog

I am using the following code to open SaveFileDialog to save CSV/TXT files:

```
    SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveDialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.CSV)|*.CSV|CSV Files (*.TXT)|*.TXT";
    saveDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    saveDialog.Title = "Save As";
    saveDialog.FileName = justFileName;
    saveDialog.InitialDirectory = "::{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}"; // For local network
```

I am following this doc to use CLSID to specify the default directory: https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13591-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-8-a.html

This code is part of a custom CSV reader, which I have written and this custom program sits on a server. I want the users to be able to save their CSV file only on their PC and not on the server.
So I was wondering how I can hide the File System/Directory Structure of the server, which is shown from the SaveFileDialog, and only show the user's local PC where the file needs to be saved?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off tackling the problem at the source - setup permissions on the network so users can't write to particular servers and shares.

Otherwise there is nothing to stop someone **saving locally** then **copying** the file to the **server** later.

Also, I don't quite understand why you went to the trouble of setting the initial folder to be **Network** *shell namespace* if your intent is **not** to save there by default.